# Inserir na tabela só a linha preenchida

Tags: php, mysql

Código da tabela:

```
$j = 0;
while($rows_cursos1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos1)) {

$tabela2 .= '<tr>';

$tabela2 .= '<td> <input type="text" readonly="true" size="20" name= "Carro[]" id= "Carro" value="'.$rows_cursos1['Descricao'].'"></td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="checkbox" name= "Selecionado['.$j.']" value="X">';

$tabela2 .= '</tr>'; 
$j++;
}
echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";
echo $tabela2;
echo "<input type='submit' name='registar' value='Registo'>";

echo "</form>";
```

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código para inserir:

```
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{

$Carro = $_POST['Carro'];


for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Carro"]);$i++) { 
$car = $_POST['Carro'][$i];
$selecionado = $_POST['Selecionado'][$i];  

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Registolistagem (Carro, Selecionado) VALUES ('$car', '$selecionado')");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 

}
}
```

Está a inserir os 6 tipos de carros que existem na tabela, mas pretendo que só insira a linha em que preencho a checkbox.
Mostro exemplo na imagem e só devia inserir a linha rodeada a vermelho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi desta forma, mas não sei se será a melhor prática:

```
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{

$Carro = $_POST['Carro'];


for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Carro"]);$i++) { 
$car = $_POST['Carro'][$i];
$selecionado = $_POST['Selecionado'][$i];  

if( $selecionado != ""){

$selecionado = $selecionado == "on" ? "X" : "";
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Registolistagem (Carro, Selecionado) VALUES ('$car', '$selecionado')");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 

}
}
}
```

Acrescentei um if para verificar se a chckbox é diferente de vazio e se for só nesse caso é que insere na tabela da base de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Vejo duas abordagens possíveis:

1. Não enviar para o servidor os valores que não estão preenchidos (usando Javascript);
2. Filtrar os dados recebidos no servidor e remover os inputs que não estão preenchidos.

Como dados devem ser validados no servidor, a opção 2 é obrigatória mas nada impede que você use a validação no cliente juntamente com a validação no servidor para melhorar a experiência do usuário.

Vou tentar explicar como pode ser feito:

#### Validação no cliente

Você pode usar javascript para modificar a propriedade [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled) dos inputs, desta maneira o navegador enviará apenas os inputs que forem `disabled = false`.

No exemplo a seguir uso [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) e [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) para buscar os elementos no DOM, itero sobre o resultado e escuto o evento `change` usando [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Cada vez que o estado de um `checkbox` muda, eu percorro o DOM começando do `checkbox` alterado, subo até o `tr` utilizando a propriedade somente-leitura [`Element.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) (você pode usar [`Element.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) se você  precisa de compatibilidade com navegadores mais "exóticos"). Partindo do `tr` eu busco o `input`, alterando sua propriedade [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled) baseado na propriedade [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#checked) do `checkbox` "clicado".

```js
let checks = document.querySelectorAll('.check')

for (let i=0, l=checks.length ; i<l ; i++) {
    checks[i].addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        let tr = this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
        tr.querySelector('.carro').disabled = !this.checked
    })
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Carro</th>
      <th>Selecione</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="Carro[]" class="carro" value="Modelo 1"></td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input class="check" type="checkbox" checked>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="Carro[]" class="carro" value="Modelo 2"></td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input class="check" type="checkbox" checked>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="Carro[]" class="carro" value="Modelo 3"></td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input class="check" type="checkbox" checked>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Validação no Servidor

Aparentemente não há a necessidade de você receber no servidor se o elemento foi selecionado ou não, basta que receba os carros e estes não estejam vazios.

Para isso você poderia usar a função [`array_map()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) juntamente com a função [`trim()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) para remover todos os espaços excedentes dos elementos do array. Após isso você pode usar [esta "gambiarra"](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#111091) (que nesse caso não é pois realmente queremos filtrar apenas as strings que tenham tamanho maior que `0`) juntando [`array_filter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) com [`strlen`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) para remover as strings vazias do nosso array.

Feito isso o resultado será apenas os carros recebidos do `form` anterior que estão prenchidos.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$carros = ["Modelo 1", "", "      ", "Modelo 2"];

// Remover espaços
$carros = array_map('trim', $carros);

// Remover elementos vazios
$carros = array_filter($carros, 'strlen');
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/DampGrayManagement) com o código funcionando.</sup>